# gcc: unrecognized option `-nolibc`

Tags: gcc, command-line

As per [gcc's linker options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-nolibc), there is supposed to be a `-nolibc` option.
However, if I try to link an object file with this option, I get an *unrecognized command line option* error. I am using gcc version 8.1.1.

So, am I missing something or is the documentation not in sync with my gcc executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual you are looking at - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ - is the manual
for the current *development* branch of GCC. See [the caveat here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

> Current development
>
> Please note that the following documentation refers to current development. Some information may not be applicable to any existing release.

The `-nolibc` option is not yet provided in a released version of GCC. See [the linker options for the latest version, 8.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

To find the manual for the GCC version your are using, select it from [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)